# slow pushing when a tableview element is selected

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, performance

In my app,i am using tableviews, populated through XML parsing, i get my XML from an ftp, the XML contains other xml urls for the next views and images urls and text, the problem is when an element of the tableview is selected it pushes to another view, But load for a very long time.
I run my app into the simulator, i never tested it on a device.

does anybody knows what may be the problem?

Is it a connection issue?

will it work fine on a device?

Comment: It would be helpful to post some of your code that handles the transition from one view to the next.  Is it through a segue or do you push it on manually?  What type of setting up are you doing before it pushes on?  Need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest testing your code on a device and not making assumptions about the peformace. I assume you are going to the server and ask for those images to display in the pushed view.  In which case you should load the view with image placeholders and spin off the downloading images in a secondary thread (good habit for slow loading as to not block the UI) and update the image placeholders as the image data become available.

I will gladly update this answer if you need more specific help.

If you are loading a tableview in your pushed view, the hang will happen on the view before that pushed view (that is very terrible UX).  So move the logic of the code that take a while into the subclass of the "pushed view", you can implement something like a spinner (I use MBProgressHud) while you crunch you data. This way you will get the view loaded before the lag begins.

Now the flow to improve UX can be as follows:
1. In the `- (void)viewDidLoad`of the pushed view you can hide the tableview (or not).

```
    [self.myTable setHidden:YES];
```

2. In the `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` of the pushed view throw up a spinner for the user to know you are doing work (work here being going to the server to look for the images from the urls) and do the work.

```
    //your code here will vary
```

3. When you know that  all your data is downloaded just load the table, hide the spinner and show the table. You can do this at the end of the `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` method.

```
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    [myTable reloadData];
```

I recommend sending all the expensive work into a secondary thread, because a user would hate to decide not to wait and have a blocked back button in the navigation bar.  But for to answer you original question you pushed view should load immediately, but then wait to get the data.

Comment: i understand what you mean but the problem is that it doesn't push to the view before everything is loaded (it freeze a while on the tableview on which i selected an item), i guess it's because the downloading is on the main thread, it would be nice if you can give a little bit more details. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I am assuming again (please correct me if I am wrong).  If you are loading something like a tableview on the pushed view and you have the delegate and datasource code on that view, it will do all the delegate and datasource work before it actually pushes the view and that will cause a hang (it will do the viewdidload work first too). If that is the case let me know, I can assist you in that particular problem.  Doing the downloading on the main thread is a recipe for UI problems but if my assumption is correct we must first address that issue. Let me know.

Comment: you're right i am using a tableView on the pushed view, but actually it hangs before it pushes to the view (the selected cell is highlighted while it hangs), for a while about 20seconds and then it pushes and shows the view like i wanted to be shown.

Comment: excellent i will see what i can do with this! i hop it will work, if you find a tutorial about somthing like this please let me know

Comment: I have done this, what specific code would you need? if you need help using the MBProgressHud or spinning off a new thread I can add another answer.

Comment: if you can commit a sample example on github that would be nice